# DHE parameters: which parameters need to be random each time?

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, key-derivation

In DH key exchange, first, both parties need to agree on a generator $g$ and prime $p$. After that each party computes its key (party A: $g^a \bmod p$) and (party B: $g^b \bmod p$), then they exchange these values to compute the shared secret. Can you please clarify which of these numbers should be random for each session (assume it is used with a protocol like TLS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: $a$ and $b$.

---

For DHE in the multiplicative group modulo $p$, it is agreed on a large prime $p$ and an element $g$. This is typically long term, and there are standard public parameters, e.g. the [3072-bit MODP group of RFC 3526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526#page-4)

After this, each time two parties A and B want a shared secret

- party A draws a random $a$ and sends $h_A = g^a\bmod p$ and
- party B draws a random $b$ and sends $h_B = g^b\bmod p$.
- party A receives $h_B$ and computes $s_A={h_B}^a\bmod p$ and
- party B receives $h_A$ and computes $s_B={h_A}^b\bmod p$.

If no message has been altered, $s_A=s_B$ and this is a shared secret $s$. It is typically used as input to a key derivation function or hash in order to generate some shared secret symmetric key(s).

More precisely, if the order of $g$ is a large prime (including when $(p-1)/2$ is prime and $g^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p=1$ and $1<g<p$), and $a$ and $b$ are uniformly random, independent, secret, and large enough, a passive adversary can not distinguish $s$ from a random element of the subgroup generated by $g$. Beware that the party sending its $h$ second can influence $s$ to some degree. Also, when $g$ is a generator of $[1,p)$ as in the question, the order of $g$ is $p-1$, thus even, and the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac sp\right)$ leaks. This is a consideration when using DHE without a key derivation function, discussed [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/78064/555).

The system was published by Withfield Diffie and Martin Hellman: [*New Directions in Cryptography*](https://ee.stanford.edu/%7Ehellman/publications/24.pdf#page=6), in [IEEE Transactions in Information Theory, 1976](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIT.1976.1055638), with some presentations in 1975. See [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20362/555) for how it was discovered but not published by Malcolm John Williamson, working for the GCHQ, in 1974.

---

Note: Nothing immediately disastrous happens if a single one of $a$ or $b$ is kept constant (making the corresponding $h_A$ or $h_B$ constant). However that *static ephemeral* setup is generally a bad idea for key exchange, because there remains no protection against a bad RNG on the side responsible for choosing the remaining random. Also, because it is used for a long time, the constant secret is more likely to leak, revealing all shared secrets. These are reasons why TLS 1.3 requires *ephemeral ephemeral* DHE (see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67606/555)). When online key exchange is not an option, a secret must nevertheless be fixed: DHE becomes the first step of ElGamal encryption, with the static $h_A$ the public key for A, and $a$ the matching private key.

If we make both $a$ and $b$ static, the shared secret becomes a constant. That can still be useful (e.g. after a key derivation step with a random value), but this *static static* setup is hardly a key exchange protocol.

---

Note: In practice, in protocols like TLS, the exchange has extra steps in order to authenticate the parties using public/private key pairs, and guard against active attacks including Man in the Middle. This is Authenticated Diffie-Hellman key Exchange.

---

Note: the question says "each party computes its key", but $h_A$, $h_B$ are normally not considered "keys" in DHE. Only for static $a$ or $b$ are $h_A$ or $h_B$ said to be "public keys". $s_A$, $s_B$, normally the same, often are called the "shared key", although I prefer "shared secret", to distinguish from the output of a later key derivation step.

Comment: @fgrieu corrected the noted errors. You can delete them from your answer now I guess not to confuse the reader.

Comment: The original paper [New Directions in Cryptography](https://ee.stanford.edu/~hellman/publications/24.pdf)